# Can I change the fristweekofyear property in DatePart to whatever I want?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-date-functions

I work for a company that has a very weird fiscal year. Their FY starts in November. I want to use DatePart function to get the Month, Quarter, and Year data out of a specified date, but I need to make sure they are sorted based on whenever the first week of the year is. How can I change that value to make it that year starts in November?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a *pseudo calendar date* from the financial year date. Then you can perform all the usual calculations etc.

Here are some code snippets to get you started:

```vb
Option Explicit

' A fiscal year is designated as the calendar year in which it ends.
' For example, if the fiscal year runs from June 1, 2022, to May 31, 2023,
' it could be designated:
'
'   financial year 2023
'   fiscal year 2023
'   FY2023
'
' Initially, call function SetFinancialStartMonth or SetFinancialEndMonth to
' define the financial/fiscal year.


' Constants.

    ' Default start day and month of the financial/fiscal year applied a
    ' neutral year for storing the values as a Date value.
    Private Const DefaultStart          As Date = #1/1/2000#
    ' Maximum day value valid for any month and year.
    Private Const MaxDayAllMonthsValue  As Integer = 28


' Statics.

    ' Local static variable to hold the selected start day and month of the financial/fiscal year.
    ' These are defined and read by the function:
    '
    '   SetFinancialStart
    '   SetFinancialEnd
    '
    Private FinancialStart  As Date


' Returns a calendar date as its equivalent pseudo date of the financial/fiscal year.
' This is mostly useful for creating search criteria, or to obtain the quarter, the
' month, or the year of the financial/fiscal year for a calendar date.
'
' 2019-10-06. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateFinancial( _
    ByVal CalendarDate As Date) _
    As Date

    Dim StartMonth      As Integer
    Dim StartDay        As Integer
    Dim Days            As Integer
    Dim FinancialDate   As Date

    StartMonth = Month(GetFinancialStart)
    StartDay = Day(GetFinancialStart)

    FinancialDate = DateAdd("m", MinMonthValue - StartMonth + MaxMonthValue, CalendarDate)

    ' Correct ultimo month dates of CalendarDate.
    If Day(CalendarDate) > Day(FinancialDate) Then
        Days = DaysInMonth(CalendarDate)
    Else
        Days = DaysInMonth(FinancialDate)
    End If
    FinancialDate = DateAdd("d", MinDayValue - StartDay + Days, FinancialDate)

    DateFinancial = FinancialDate

End Function


' Returns the financial start month and day as a Date value applied a neutral year.
' If the start month and day have not been set, the default value is returned.
'
' 2019-01-26. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function GetFinancialStart() As Date

    If FinancialStart = #12:00:00 AM# Then
        ' Set default value for start date.
        SetFinancialStart
    End If

    GetFinancialStart = FinancialStart

End Function


' Sets the start day and month of the financial/fiscal year as a
' date value applied a neutral year.
'
' The start month can be any month.
' The start day can be any day less than or equal 28, which is the
' highest day value valid for any month.
'
' Default value is January 1st.
'
' 2019-01-26. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub SetFinancialStart( _
    Optional ByVal StartMonth As Integer = MinMonthValue, _
    Optional ByVal StartDay As Integer = MinDayValue)

    Const MaxMonthValue          As Integer = 12
    Const MinMonthValue          As Integer = 1
    Const MinDayValue            As Integer = 1

    ' Validate input.
    If StartMonth < MinMonthValue Or _
        StartMonth > MaxMonthValue Or _
        StartDay < MinDayValue Or _
        StartDay >= MaxDayAllMonthsValue Then
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
    End If

    FinancialStart = DateSerial(Year(DefaultStart), StartMonth, StartDay)

End Sub



' Sets - based on the end day and month - the start day and month of the
' financial/fiscal year as a date value applied a neutral year.
'
' The end month can be any month.
' The end day can be any day larger than 1. If end day is larger than 28,
' which is the highest day value valid for any month, start day is set to 1.
'
' Default value is January 1st.
'
' 2019-01-26. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Sub SetFinancialEnd( _
    Optional ByVal EndMonth As Integer = MaxMonthValue, _
    Optional ByVal EndDay As Integer = MaxDayValue)

    Dim StartMonth As Integer
    Dim StartDay As Integer

    ' Validate input.
    If EndMonth < MinMonthValue Or _
        EndMonth > MaxMonthValue Or _
        EndDay < MinDayValue Or _
        EndDay > MaxDayValue Then
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
    End If

    If EndDay < MaxDayAllMonthsValue - 1 Then
        ' Set start date of the financial year as the day after the end day.
        StartMonth = EndMonth
        StartDay = EndDay + 1
    Else
        ' Set start date of the financial year as primo next month.
        StartMonth = EndMonth Mod MonthsPerYear + 1
        StartDay = 1
    End If

    SetFinancialStart StartMonth, StartDay

End Sub



' Returns the count of days of the month of Date1.
'
' 2016-02-14. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DaysInMonth( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date) _
    As Integer

    Const MaxDateValue           As Date = #12/31/9999#
    Const MaxDayValue            As Integer = 31

    Dim Days    As Integer

    If DateDiff("m", Date1, MaxDateValue) = 0 Then
        Days = MaxDayValue
    Else
        Days = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date1), Month(Date1) + 1, 0))
    End If

    DaysInMonth = Days

End Function
```